# ngx-gallery: How to get active image?

Tags: angular, typescript, gallery, image-gallery

In the documentation, there is only adding of style to the active thumbnail of the slider. But how do you get the data bound from the active image?

https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get active/selected index by getting component instance, Example shown below

```
import { NgxGalleryComponent } from "ngx-gallery";
...
@ViewChild(NgxGalleryComponent) ngxGalleryComponent;
...
ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.ngxGalleryComponent.selectedIndex);
}
```

You can use selectedIndex to get active item/data `this.galleryImages[this.ngxGalleryComponent.selectedIndex]`
Hope this helps :)